# MySQL auto increment refresh with new ID

Tags: mysql, increment

I have a table, in MySQL where events are posted by users. Their individual ID is posted, so all the events they post can be related to their account. However, I want to put an auto increment field, that only count the events for 1 user at the time.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I achieve it?

For example, if the user with the ID 544 post 4 events, the 4th one will be marked as 4 in the auto increment column, even if it's the 421 events in the table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put in such a field, but you would need a trigger to keep it up-to-date.  Then, if rows are updated or deleted, maintaining becomes challenging.

You can simulate this in a query pretty easily though, using variables:

```
select e.*,
       @rn := if(@userid = userid, 1, @rn + 1) as UserSequenceNumber,
       @userid := userid
from events e cross join
     (select @rn := 0) const
order by userid;
```

You can also incorporate this into an `update` statement, if you want to actually store the values in the table.  Once again, let me say, keeping the value up to date requires a bunch of triggers.

Also, the above works in practice.  However, MySQL does not *guarantee* that arguments are processed in order.  So, in theory, the `@userid` could be assigned before `@rn`, but this doesn't seem to happen in practice.